# Change class name of div inside anchor element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function onClickEv(child){
  //change the class from div_className to div_newClass
  console.log(child);
}
```

```html
<a href="page url" id="a_idName" target="_blank" onclick="onClickEv(this)" class="a_className">
   <div class="div_className">text here</div>
</a>
```

How can I change the class attribute value of div inside the anchor element in `onclick` event `"onClickEv"` in my external javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: Add `child.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "div_newClassName";` this line in your `onClickEv` function. It will works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change class name in javascript as shown below code snippet.

```js
function onClickEv(child){
  //change the class from div_className to div_newClass
   
 child.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "div_newClassName";

   console.log(document.getElementById("a_idName").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<a href="page url" id="a_idName" target="_blank" onclick="onClickEv(this)" class="a_className">
   <div class="div_className">text here</div>
</a>
```

**OR**

You can do it using JQuery `addClass`, `removeClass` function.

Replace below line in `onClickEv` function and add jQuery library in html header.

```
$("#a_idName div").removeClass('div_className').addClass('div_newClassName');
```

Comment: @ezekiel Please accept as answer if you are able to solve problem using above solution.

Comment: I have updated answer. please check it, may be help to solve your problem.

Comment: that new code update solve my problem. thanks. But what is the purpose of **[0]** in  child.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "div_newClassName"; I'm just curious..

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns list of element. In your case, inside anchor tag have a single div. So we taking first element from it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign an Id to your Div element and use below code to achieve this :

```
var element = document.getElementById("div-id");
if (element !== null) {
  if (element.className == "div_className") {
    element.className = "div_newClassName";
  } else {
    // add this else only in case you want to toggle the class
    element.className = "div_className";
  }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple anchor with a child div. What I want is to change the class attribute value of the one I click, that's why I use the **this** as the parameter of my function onClickEv(child).